# Kotlin Flows: StateFlow or distinct+conflated?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I've got a bizarre file that is always the same size, with the same modified date.  (some driver showing its state as a file's contents through a fake filesystem). It contains a short string that changes when the device's state changes.  I don't think I can [Watch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) the file because it is a fake filesystem. Cool so far!

I was hoping to modernize it!  *A changing file that may or may not have anyone listening feels like a flow.*

I'm not entirely sure about **[distinctUntilChanged](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/distinct-until-changed.html)** and **[conflate](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/conflate.html)** (do they play nice together?) and if I'm just reinventing a **[StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/)**?

```kotlin
fun fileChanges(file: File): Flow<String> = flow {
    while (true) {
        emit(file.readText(charset))
        delay(1)
    }
}
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) // Run in background
    .distinctUntilChanged() // no duplicate status
    .conflate() // only most recent
    .map { it.trim() } // just the one line without newlines
```

This seems to work (with the expected system overhead) and I'm only trimming the deduped values, but... it smells funny.  Like I should be able to reuse file handles, or memory mapped stuff, or a mark()/reset(), or better still, wrap it all up in a [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) object.

Comment: It depends a bit on the context. If there is only one consumer, your implementation looks like the way to go. StateFlow will allow you to share the same event stream with multiple consumers but forces you to stop polling explicitly.

Comment: @AdrianK If I did want to share with multiple consumers, then any thoughts on what would replace the polling?

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun excercise since I am also still learning how to utilize flows the best way. Thanks for that. 
This is what I came up with:

```
class PollingFileWatcher(private val file: File, private val pollingInterval: Long) {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private val state = MutableStateFlow("") //initial state doesn't matter, we will update it directly when starting to poll anyway
    private var pollingJob: Job? = null
    private var subscriptions = 0 // keep track of how many observers there are, start polling if this changes 0 -> 1, stop polling if it changes 1 -> 0

    private fun readContent(): String {
        return file.readText(Charset.defaultCharset()) //Or whatever Charset fits
    }

    private fun createPollingJob() = scope.launch {
        while (isActive) {
            state.value = readContent()
            delay(pollingInterval)
        }
    }

    private fun startPolling() {
        state.value = readContent() // update to latest value before subscribers start collecting, otherwise they might get the useless initial value
        pollingJob = createPollingJob()
    }

    private fun stopPolling() {
        pollingJob?.cancel()
        pollingJob = null
    }

    private fun onSubscribe() = synchronized(this) {
        if (subscriptions++ == 0) { // changed from 0 to 1
            startPolling()
        }
    }

    private fun onUnsubscribe() = synchronized(this) {
        if (--subscriptions == 0) { // changed from 1 to 0
            stopPolling()
        }
    }

    fun changes() = flow {
        onSubscribe()
        try {
            state.collect {
                emit(it)
            }
        } finally { // e.g. the collecting context has been cancelled
            onUnsubscribe()
        }
    }
}
```

This can probably be generalized for any sort of long running jobs but that might be a bit too much.

In general, polling is started when the first collector starts collecting and is cancelled when the last one stops collecting. In short: If no one is watching, no work is done. 
The `MutableStateFlow` will automatically cache the latest value and immediately emit it to a new collector, as well as drop duplicate values (comparison is done with `equals`)

Example usage:

```
val watcher = PollingFileWatcher(File("/path/to/the/file"), 100)
GlobalScope.launch{ // please never actually use GlobalScope
    watcher.changes().collect{
      // TODO 
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks great but I have a question: I thought Flows were cold, meaning "if there are subscribers, do your thing, otherwise don't bother" which would do most of this for you.  (I am also just learning flows, so I may be off with that understanding.)

Comment: Usually, you would be right. But MutableStateFlow is an exception to that rule. 
It can not finish, e.g. signal collectors that no new values will be emitted, nor propagate failures.
The above code coud still be considered somwhat cold, since it starts and stops dependening on whether it is observer

Comment: Ah!  That mostly makes sense.  So the "flow" part of MutableStateFlow is kinda misleading, because without your code above it isn't cold, and flows are cold.  It feels like an https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/observer-pattern

Comment: @BenjaminH Some flows are cold, some flows are hot. Not all flows are cold.